# How to rebind button's click event using .on/off

Tags: javascript, jquery

For binding and unbind event handlers I'm using **on()/off()** event handler attachment.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='load' class="UnfiledContainer">
    <button onclick="loaded()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#sync_img').on('click', function () {
    alert("Sync");
});

loaded = function () {
    $('#sync_img').off('click');  //Works perfectly
    var x = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x = x + "Thenumberis" + i;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    $('#sync_img').on('click');   // This is not rebinding the click event
}
```

When user clicks `#sync_img`, I will show an alert.  Whereas when `#load`, I'm unbinding the click event of `#sync_img` using **.off()**.

I tried rebinding it using **.on()** yet I was not able to rebind it.

Here is the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XwaYd/)

Please share your suggestion.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $('#sync_img').on('click');   you have to specify a handler!

Comment: @roasted whereas for `.off()` I'm not specifying a handler.  Will this affect my code?

Comment: No, check the DOC. Even you should use event namespaced instead of raw event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **specify the eventHandler** again if you want to  rebind the event.

```
 // Bind the event
   $('#sync_img').on('click', clickEvent); 

   // Remove the handler
   $('#sync_img').off('click'); 

   // Need to rebind the event passing in the handler again
    $('#sync_img').on('click', clickEvent); 

    function clickEvent() {
       alert("Sync");
    }
```

Otherwise it wouldn't know what handler it has to bound to.

Cause you can bind multiple hanlders to a single event.

```
$('#sync_img').on('click', clickEvent1);
$('#sync_img').on('click', clickEvent2);
```

So when you want to unbind all the click events .You would use

```
$('#sync_img').off('click');
```

But if you only want to unbind a single event then you would just pass in the handler that is to be removed

```
$('#sync_img').off('click', clickEvent1);
```

This only removes the first handler. But the other handler still fires since only the 1st one was removed.

**[Unbind All handlers](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4CumK/)**

**[Unbind a specific handler](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/4CumK/1/)**